# overwriting a spark output using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to overwrite a Spark dataframe using the following option in PySpark but I am not successful

```
spark_df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("header", "true",mode='overwrite').save(self.output_file_path)
```

the mode=overwrite command is not successful

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Try:

```
spark_df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
  .mode('overwrite').option("header", "true").save(self.output_file_path)
```

Comment: it worked for updating json file on hdfs `doc.write.format('json').mode("append").option("header","true").save(/path/to/hdfs_file)`

Answer (score 30):

Spark 1.4 and above has a built in csv function for the dataframewriter

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter

e.g.

```
spark_df.write.csv(path=self.output_file_path, header="true", mode="overwrite", sep="\t")
```

Which is syntactic sugar for

```
spark_df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").options(header="true",sep="\t").save(path=self.output_file_path)
```

I think what is confusing is finding where exactly the options are available for each format in the docs.

These write related methods belong to the `DataFrameWriter` class:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter

The `csv` method has these options available, also available when using `format("csv")`:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv

The way you need to supply parameters also depends on if the method takes a single `(key, value)` tuple or keyword args. It's fairly standard to the way python works generally though, using (*args, **kwargs), it just differs from the Scala syntax.

For example
The `option(key, value)` method takes one option as a tuple like `option(header,"true")` and the `.options(**options)` method takes a bunch of keyword assignments e.g. `.options(header="true",sep="\t")`

### EDIT 2021

The docs have had a huge facelift which may be good from the perspective of new users discovering functionality from a requirement perspective, but does need some adjusting to.

DataframeReader and DataframeWriter are now part of the Input/Output in the API docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql.html#input-and-output

The DataframeWriter.csv callable is now here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv

### Update 2023

Docs changed again. DataFrameWriter.csv: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv