# How to append to a csv file using df.write.csv in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to append data to my csv file using `df.write.csv`. This is what I did after following spark document http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameWriter
.....
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(query1)
df1.write.csv("/opt/Output/sqlcsvA.csv", append) #also tried 'mode=append'
```

Executing the above code gives me error:

> NameError: name 'append' not defined

Without append, error:

> The path already exists.

Comment: are there a file called by sqlcsvA.csv?

Comment: Yes  the output is copied to `sqlcsvA.csv` file.

Comment: can you delete and again create this file from code ?

Comment: Are you asking to add a delete option in code and then each time program runs a new file should be created?

Answer (score 15):

```
df.write.save(path='csv', format='csv', mode='append', sep='\t')
```

Comment: This again splits output into different files. It's gets partitioned.

Comment: Include `.coalesce(1)` before write, it will prevent partitioning, not sure if the result will be appended though!  
`df.coalesce(1).write.save(path='csv', format='csv', mode='append', sep='\t')`

Comment: Thanks. That got everything to one file.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter
Since v1.4

`csv(path, mode=None, compression=None, sep=None, quote=None, escape=None, header=None, nullValue=None, escapeQuotes=None, quoteAll=None, dateFormat=None, timestampFormat=None)`

e.g.

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameWriter
.....
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(query1)
df1.write.csv(path="/opt/Output/sqlcsvA.csv", mode="append")
```

If you want to write a single file, you can use coalesce or `repartition` on either of those lines. It doesn't matter which line, because the dataframe is just a DAG execution , no execution happens until the write to csv.  `repartition` & `coalesce` effectively use the same code, but coalesce can only reduce the number of partitions where `repartition` can also increase them. I'd just stick to `repartition` for simplicity.

e.g.

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(query1).repartition(1)
```

or

```
df1.repartition(1).write.csv(path="/opt/Output/sqlcsvA.csv", mode="append")
```

I think the examples in the docs aren't great, they don't show examples of using parameters other than the path.

Referring to the two things you tried:

`(append)`

For that to work, there would need to be a string variable named append containing the value "append". There's no string constant in the DataFrameWriter library called append. 
i.e. you could add this earlier in your code, and it would then work. 
append = "append"

`('mode=append')`

For that to work, the csv method would have to parse out the `mode=append` string to get the value for the mode, which would be extra work when you can just have a parameter with exactly the value "append" or "overwrite" that needs to be extracted. None is a special case, Python built in, not specific to pyspark.

On another note, I recommend using named parameters where possible.
e.g.

```
csv(path="/path/to/file.csv", mode="append")
```

instead of positional parameters

```
csv("/path/to/file.csv", "append")
```

It's clearer, and helps comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

I do not about Python, but in Scala and Java one can set the the save mode in the following way:

```
df.write.mode("append").csv("pathToFile")
```

I assume that it should be similar in Python. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861099/overwriting-a-spark-output-using-pyspark) may be helpful.

Comment: I tried what you said in python. But each line of my output is copied into separate csv files in one folder called `sqlcsvA.csv`. They are not copied into one single csv file.

Comment: @kaks, it seems like you will have to merge those files manually. Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674530/write-single-csv-file-using-spark-csv). For instance, people are using [FileUtil.copyMerge](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#copyMerge(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.String)) in Java.

Comment: @kaks, note that if you read the results back (in Spark), those files are merged and you have a DataFrame that contains the data from all files in that directory.

Comment: Don't need to merge them manually, just use `.repartition(1)` when writing. When you read the files back in to a dataframe, it doesn't technically merge them, because the dataframe is distributed in the cluster. Each file will be the basis of a dataframe partition. So in a sense you do have one dataframe, but it is still in many underlying pieces.